# Fundraiser wallet issues

Tags: wallets

I have a couple of questions for the experts:

I have access to my fundraiser wallet using the Chrome extension. I had baked using a contract (KT account), and I cannot send from the KT account using the extension (forge error)

I have restored access to my fundraiser wallet using Tezbox Windows App.
Sadly, the contract doesn't show after the restore, only the main account.

My questions are as follows:

How to restore access to the KT contract as well?

Do I need to stop delegating before sending?

Why am I getting a forge error? I am using medium fees and sending only 1 XTZ

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stop using tezbox. It’s no longer maintained. Use other wallets like galleon, ledger live, atomex, kukai etc

Comment: How do they support ICO wallet?

Comment: you can import fundraiser wallet in galleon